# Get the number of levels in a column matching each level of another column

Tags: r

Imagine I have this dataframe:

```
Gene   Sample
TP53     A
KRAS     B
TP53     B
CMYC     C
HB1      D
TP53     D
ERBB     E
BRCA1    T
KRAS     B
BRCA1    T
```

How can I get the number of samples in which each gene is active? in other words, how can I get the number of factors of column "Sample" matching to each factor of column "Gene"?

My desired output would be:

```
Gene   Sample
TP53     3
KRAS     1
CMYC     1
HB1      1
ERBB     1
BRCA1    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unique()` and `table()`.

```
table(unique(df)$Gene)

# BRCA1  CMYC  ERBB   HB1  KRAS  TP53 
#     1     1     1     1     1     3
```

---

`dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% distinct %>% count(Gene)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Gene      n
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 BRCA1     1
# 2 CMYC      1
# 3 ERBB      1
# 4 HB1       1
# 5 KRAS      1
# 6 TP53      3
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution using `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  summarise(Sample = n_distinct(Sample))
```

---

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Gene  Sample
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 BRCA1      1
# 2 CMYC       1
# 3 ERBB       1
# 4 HB1        1
# 5 KRAS       1
# 6 TP53       3
```